# Riemannian geometry before semi-Riemannian geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am interested in getting acquainted with semi-Riemannian geometry for application in general relativity. For this, it seems O'Neill's book is considered the "gold standard". I am acquainted with basic smooth manifold theory on the level of Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds* but am concerned my preparation may be inadequate. Is it recommended that the reader have an acquaintance with Riemannian geometry, e.g. the first 8 chapters of Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*, before attempting to tackle the more general semi-Riemannian geometry? Is there a compelling reason to (or not to) study Riemannian geometry first?

Comment: In my opinion, just try reading O'Neill and use Lee as a reference text if something confuses you.

Comment: It never hurts first to learn a little bit of undergraduate differential geometry (basics of curves and surfaces) to develop intuition and have some idea what a connection is.

Comment: I didn't say this is recommended, but I was a physics student and I learned semi-Riemannian geometry (physicist version) and Curves and Surfaces first. Then I read Lee's RG after I felt comfortable working with manifolds.

Comment: I learned curves and surfaces in Euclidean space and Minkowski space at the same time, it helped me appreciate better the importance of positivity in several Euclidean proofs and didn't hurt at all. I'll second what Max said, just try to read O'Neill and use another Riemannian geometry book as a backup for more concrete examples and so on. I love O'Neill's book, but I have to warn you it can be a difficult first-time read (every time I pick the thing I understand something that went over my head before, so "gold standard" sounds very adequate).